# How to detect the presence of an object in a non-stationary background using Opencv in Android?

Tags: java, image-processing, computer-vision, android, opencv

I'm developing an application to process frames and do segmentation and image matching in real time using Opencv in Android.

The main problem is that I need to start this image processing only when object to process is available in camera frame and the background is non-stationary which make my task harder.

I tried many solution like motion detection using `absdiff` and this is the code

```
    imgSource = inputFrame.rgba().t();
    Core.transpose(imgSource, imgSource);

    //imgSource.convertTo(enhancedMat, imgSource.type(), 1.3);



    gray = imgSource;
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gray, gray, new Size(25, 25), 5);
    if (firstframe == null) {
        firstframe = gray;
    }
    Core.absdiff(firstframe, gray, frameDelta);
    Imgproc.threshold(frameDelta, frameDelta, 25, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    for (int i =0 ; i <2 ; i++)
        Imgproc.dilate(frameDelta, frameDelta, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, new Size(3, 3)));

    Imgproc.findContours(frameDelta, abs_contours, abs_hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < abs_contours.size(); idx++) {

        double a = Imgproc.contourArea(abs_contours.get(idx));  //Find the area of contour

        if (a < 10000) {

            continue;
        }

        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(abs_contours.get(idx));
        Imgproc.rectangle(imgSource, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    }
```

i also tried background substraction using this Opencv method `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2`.

None of them worked because the background is moving too so those logics aren't robust at all.

Is there any approach I must follow or any solution for this kind of problem ?

I hope you guys can guide me to a good solution and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To face this issue, I used **optical flow**.

You can compute the optical flow on each frame using `calcOpticalFlowFarneback`.

Then, you get a matrix of 2 components (gradient in x direction and y direction) for each pixel of your image.

I computed for each point `atan2(flow_y,flow_x)` and stored it in a `vector<Point2f>`.

Then, just do a clusterization using kmeans and with 2 labels. (to differenciate the background to the foreground moving objects in the sequence).

The returned matrix from kmeans give you the labels.

Hope it helps !

**EDIT :**

I've been working with OpenCV C++ but here is my code

```
int calculateOptFlow(Mat prev_frame, Mat frame, Mat& output) 
{
    Mat flow;

    //the algorithm uses gray images
    cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(prev_frame,prev_frame,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_frame, frame, flow,0.4, 1, 12, 2, 8, 1.2, 0);

    Mat angle(flow.rows,flow.cols,CV_32FC1);
    Mat dst(flow.rows,flow.cols,CV_32FC1);
    vector<Point2f> samples(flow.rows*flow.cols);

    int n=0;
    for(int y=0;y<flow.rows;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<flow.cols ; x++)
        {

            angle.at<float>(y,x) = (atan2(flow.at<Point2f>(y,x).y,flow.at<Point2f>(y,x).x));
            samples[n++] =  flow.at<Point2f>(y,x);
        }
    }

    // split into 2 clusters : background and foreground
    Mat labels,centers;
    kmeans(samples,2,labels,TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS+TermCriteria::COUNT,10,1.0),3,KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,centers);

    // create a B&W matrix from the labels
    for(int i=0;i<(int)samples.size();i++)
    {
        int row = static_cast<int>(i/dst.cols);
        int col = i%dst.cols;
        if(labels.at<int>(i) == 1)
        {
            dst.at<float>(row,col) = 255;
        }
        else
        {
            dst.at<float>(row,col) = 0;
        }
    }

    //conversion for the use of findContours afterwards
    dst.convertTo(output,CV_8UC1);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It's a good solution but I'm new to this, can you provide me an example of using **Optical flow** in android ?

Comment: Even a c++ example of the steps you provided in your answer

Comment: Can you tell me what is that variable `flow` ? is it just a copy of the `output` ?

Comment: Yes sorry I concatenated 2 functions into 1 and forgot about this variable. flow is the output of the calcOpticalFlowFarneback. I edited my code !

Comment: No problem, I'm testing it and i'll give you my results and I hope I accept your answer :)

Comment: I used your code as a JNI function and I noticed that my application freezes after calling your method and when I looked into Logs I found this exception caused by`calcOpticalFlowFarneback` : ` OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (prev0.size() == next0.size() && prev0.channels() == next0.channels() && prev0.channels() == 1 && pyrScale_ < 1) in virtual void cv::{anonymous}::FarnebackOpticalFlowImpl::calc`

Comment: I fixed the issues with just resizing my Mats to the same size.

Comment: Yea prev_frame and frame must have the same size. I had the test at the beginning of the function but I removed it for the sample code !

Comment: It's too slow process, took around 15 seconds to execute and I've got bad results. I can link some images if you would like to.

Comment: Takes approximatively 20 to 40ms for me and have very good results haha

Comment: Is it because I'm running this in an Android device?

Comment: Oh yea I forgot about this... This solution may not be viable for Android. On a computer with better configs it works good... Btw I'm running on 150x150 pixels images and the video sequences are moving but slowly

Comment: I think about using ORB to find matches, and if there is good number of matches then the object is present?

Comment: You already know what the object looks like? If so you can try this approach which might be faster. There is also the FastFeatureDetector which is.. fast !

Comment: Yes I have the reference image. Thank you for your time and help sir.

Comment: You can also try template matching by the way. If you won't deal with that much rotation you can have a look at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html . There is also homography

Comment: Great suggestion, I want the lightest way because I want only to detect the presence of the object, then I apply my detection algorthm. I'll give it a try and give you my feedback. I already implemented the ORB but I don't get results yet.

Comment: interesting link for you : https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html

Comment: Template matching isn't working , it took 20 seconds to execute and it doesn't detect my template. By the way SURF is patented protected and it doesn't have good performance in mobile devices so I think I should stick with ORB. Thank you any way :) .

Comment: If you find a good solution using ORB I'm interested in the result. Maybe you could write an answer to your own post with the code later !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190922/discussion-between-amine-and-emlot77).